# Check localStorage is set to a specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, storage, local

I'd really appreciate some help on this, I really can't see my issue here.

For some reason, sensing whether this data (loggedIn) is stored in localStorage with the value "yes" - I've tried the regular way of seeing if the localStorage is empty.

Here's my current code...

```
    <script>
    function checkLoggedIn()
    {
    if (localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === null) {
      alert("empty");
    }else{
      $(".topbar").html("<span>Saved Jobs(0)</span><span>Welcome, "+ storedUsername +"!</span>");
      alert("working");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Then obviously I would call this with a body onload. For some reason, I can physically see the value of the localStorage when passing it as a variable, but checking it seems to not be working in the slightest.

I'm using this to simulate functionality of a user logging in, the rest of the functions to handle registration and logging in work fine to actually set the localStorage - so it's not a case of it not being stored.

Thanks for any help given people, it's really appreciated.

Comment: What is `storedUsername`? Where do you define it?

Comment: What does `localStorage.getItem("loggedIn")` return?

Comment: What is happening exactly ? did you check console ? is there any error thrown ?

Comment: storedUsername is set earlier on and is already stored, therefore that isn't the issue. @Nielarshi the issue is that literally nothing is happening and I have no idea why, I'll check the console now.

Edit: My fault guys, storedUsername was the big issue - it was being defined in a totally different function and I forgot to state what it was in this function - console notified me of the error.

Thanks for all your help guys!

Comment: @TomAldy just a little note: the information that the problem is already solved is a bit hidden in the comment. As it is most likely just a _"stupid"_ mistake that won't help others it might be better to delete the question anyway.